# Module not found: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' after adding dd-trace dependency

Tags: datadog, apm

I have an FE app written in React & Node and I need to add to it dd-trace. I have run *npm install dd-trace* and afterwards it was saying that I also need to install *async_hooks*, so I run npm install async_hooks. Both commands run fine, but when I'm running npm start, I receive the following error:

> Failed to compile.
> ./node_modules/dd-trace/packages/dd-trace/src/scope/async_resource.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in PATH

I have checked that path and I have *async_resource* on that folder, but for some reason is not seen.

Any suggestions on how to fix this error or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datadog [APM](https://www.datadoghq.com/product/apm/) doesn't support running in the browser, so installing `dd-trace` wouldn't work. You should instead use [RUM](https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/) by installing the [browser SDK](https://github.com/DataDog/browser-sdk).